# URL connection failed with android

Tags: java, android, urlconnection

I tired the example of oracle to read from an URLConnection with android
this is the code

```
``try{
            URL oracle = new URL("http://www.oracle.com/");
            Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP,newInetSocketAddress("192.168.3.254",3128)); // or whatever your proxy is
            URLConnection yc = oracle.openConnection(proxy);
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(yc.getInputStream()));
            String inputLine;
            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) 
               Toast.makeText(this, inputLine, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            in.close();
        }
    catch(IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I notice that my proxy emulator setting is configured
I have this log errors

> >04-20 14:20:21.842: D/AndroidRuntime(988): Shutting down VM
> 04-20 14:20:21.842: W/dalvikvm(988): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409c01f8)
> 04-20 14:20:21.862: E/AndroidRuntime(988): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> 04-20 14:20:21.862: E/AndroidRuntime(988): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{connect.oracle.java/connect.oracle.java.ConnectActivity}: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
> 04-20 14:20:21.862: E/AndroidRuntime(988):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
> 04-20 14:20:21.862: E/AndroidRuntime(988):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
> 04-20 14:20:21.862: E/AndroidRuntime(988):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
> 04-20 14:20:21.862: E/AndroidRuntime(988):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
> 04-20 14:20:21.862: E/AndroidRuntime(988):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
> 04-20 14:20:21.862: E/AndroidRuntime(988):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
> 04-20 14:20:21.862: E/AndroidRuntime(988):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
> 04-20 14:20:21.862: E/AndroidRuntime(988):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
> 04-20 14:20:21.862: E/AndroidRuntime(988):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
> 04-20 14:20:21.862: E/AndroidRuntime(988):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
> 04-20 14:20:21.862: E/AndroidRuntime(988):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
> 04-20 14:20:21.862: E/AndroidRuntime(988):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
> 04-20 14:20:21.862: E/AndroidRuntime(988): Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
> 04-20 14:20:21.862: E/AndroidRuntime(988):  at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1099)
> 04-20 14:20:21.862: E/AndroidRuntime(988):  at java.net.InetAddress.getHostByAddrImpl(InetAddress.java:440)
> 04-20 14:20:21.862: E/AndroidRuntime(988):  at java.net.InetAddress.getHostName(InetAddress.java:313)
> 04-20 14:20:21.862: E/AndroidRuntime(988):  at java.net.InetSocketAddress.getHostName(InetSocketAddress.java:156)
> 04-20 14:20:21.862: E/AndroidRuntime(988):  at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection$Address.(HttpConnection.java:322)
> 04-20 14:20:21.862: E/AndroidRuntime(988):  at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.connect(HttpConnection.java:96)
> 04-20 14:20:21.862: E/AndroidRuntime(988):  at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.openSocketConnection(HttpEngine.java:308)
> 04-20 14:20:21.862: E/AndroidRuntime(988):  at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:303)
> 04-20 14:20:21.862: E/AndroidRuntime(988):  at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:282)
> 04-20 14:20:21.862: E/AndroidRuntime(988):  at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:232)
> 04-20 14:20:21.862: E/AndroidRuntime(988):  at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:273)
> 04-20 14:20:21.862: E/AndroidRuntime(988):  at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:168)
> 04-20 14:20:21.862: E/AndroidRuntime(988):  at connect.oracle.java.ConnectActivity.onCreate(ConnectActivity.java:22)
> 04-20 14:20:21.862: E/AndroidRuntime(988):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
> 04-20 14:20:21.862: E/AndroidRuntime(988):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
> 04-20 14:20:21.862: E/AndroidRuntime(988):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
> 04-20 14:20:21.862: E/AndroidRuntime(988):  ... 11 more

And thank you in advance

Comment: How can your code compile ? You can't declare a local variable like inputLine without assigning it a value.

Answer (score 1):

You have [Strict Mode](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/StrictMode.html) on.  It complains when you block the UI thread doing slow IO things.

Either turn strict mode off, or - always the better option - move your IO code to a background thread.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the internet permission added in your manifest file ?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Move IO code to back-ground thread (or) Asynch task (if fits in your requirement). It is not best practice to use network calls on main thread. Refer this [write-up](http://www.techblogistech.com/2011/11/how-to-fix-the-android-networkonmainthreadexception/).